# The constraint reference 'string' could not be resolved to a type. (netcoreapp3.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have got an error. This is my Startup class.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Current technology "netcoreapp3.0" and my controller is.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("request")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

And here is my error. I couldn't find a solution, I even didn't get what exactly this is. So here we are.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'string' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.DefaultParameterPolicyFactory.Create(RoutePatternParameterPart parameter, String inlineText)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.ParameterPolicyFactory.Create(RoutePatternParameterPart parameter, RoutePatternParameterPolicyReference reference)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.CreateCandidate(Endpoint endpoint, Int32 score)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.CreateCandidates(IReadOnlyList`1 endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.AddNode(DfaNode node, DfaState[] states, Int32 exitDestination)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.AddNode(DfaNode node, DfaState[] states, Int32 exitDestination)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.<AddNode>g__Transition|19_0(DfaNode next, <>c__DisplayClass19_0& )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.AddNode(DfaNode node, DfaState[] states, Int32 exitDestination)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.AddNode(DfaNode node, DfaState[] states, Int32 exitDestination)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.AddNode(DfaNode node, DfaState[] states, Int32 exitDestination)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.AddNode(DfaNode node, DfaState[] states, Int32 exitDestination)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DataSourceDependentMatcher.CreateMatcher(IReadOnlyList`1 endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.DataSourceDependentCache`1.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DataSourceDependentMatcher..ctor(EndpointDataSource dataSource, Lifetime lifetime, Func`1 matcherBuilderFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherFactory.CreateMatcher(EndpointDataSource dataSource)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.InitializeCoreAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatcher|8_0(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task`1 matcherTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

EDIT: There is my dependencies. When I remove these then it worked.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
<PackageReference Include="Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore" Version="3.0.24" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

In case you use something like

```
[HttpGet("example/{param1:string}/{param2:Guid}")]
```

change it to

```
[HttpGet("example/{param1}/{param2:Guid}")]
```

because ":string" is actually interpreted as a **regex-validation-constraint** and **not a type definition** and guess what, everything is reaching the server as string and there is no string-regex-validator :)

Comment: You did not include this as part of your question, so it would not have been possible for someone to answer this for you. You can see route constraint reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-constraint-reference.

Comment: You're right. Like I said before " I even didn't get what exactly this is." so after a couple hours debugging I got it. And I shared solution for others.

Answer (score 19):

I also encountered this recently.  The fix for me as to use "alpha" as a replacement for the string type:

```
[HttpGet("example/{param1:alpha}")]
```

This was documented in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-constraint-reference).

Comment: @Darbio Not really: "alpha" is only a partial replacement, because it requires strings consisting entirely of letters, i.e. "hello" would be accepted, but "hello123" would be rejected.

Answer (score 5):

It could be a blank space between the param name and the type.

Example:

{param1 :alpha}

{param1:alpha} ✅

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was just a single space between the route parameter and the data type ({id: int})

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, my issue was variable naming mismatch.

**Not Working**

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> Get(string userId) {
    //some code
}
```

`userId` should change to `id` to match the `{id}`

**Working**

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> Get(string id) {
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not same:

```
[HttpGet("example/{param1:string}/{param2:Guid}")]
```

as this:

```
[HttpGet("example/{param1: string}/{param2:Guid}")]
```

Check the space in the type after `param1:` in the second example.

If it recognizes a space, it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'Admin' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.

This error happen because of the configuration of midleware "MapControllerRoute" in program.cs, some persons are not change the ":" by "=".
You must replace :
pattern: "{area:Admin}/{controller=Category}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
by
pattern: "{area=Admin}/{controller=Category}/{action=Index}/{id?}"

[image: look at the part circled with red color]